# Cassandra terrible performance on select

Tags: cassandra

I have two nodes Cassandra cluster. In order to test Cassandra i built a File table (Fid Integer,Sid Integer), Which Fid is key. I built index on Sid, Insert rate is about 10,000 in 1 second. But when i select from table the performance is terrible, and for low limit like 1000 it generate error, bellow is my sample code,

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
session = cluster.connect('myk')
rows = session.execute('SELECT * FROM File WHERE sid = 1 limit 1000')
for user_row in rows:
    print user_row
```

Error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 5, in <module>
    rows = session.execute('SELECT * FROM File WHERE sid = 1 limit 1000')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\cassandra\cluster.py", line 1065, in execute
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\cassandra\cluster.py", line 2427, in result
cassandra.OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=172.16.47.130
```

by changing

```
rows = session.execute('SELECT * FROM File WHERE sid = 1 limit 1000')
```

to

```
rows = session.execute('SELECT * FROM File WHERE sid = 1 limit 1000',timeout=20.0)
```

Error has gone, but why performance (for fetching 1000 rows from a 800,000 records table) is very slow? Any hints?

Comment: look at cassandra log files...

Comment: /var/log/cassandra/system.log ?

Comment: How is the cardinality of the fid values?

Comment: Fid is primary key and table have about 800,000, means 800,000 unique values, Sid have 2 unique values and have low cardinality

Comment: Turn on tracing and share the output of a typical trace (with the 20 second timeout set). Also,the exact schema of the table would be extremely beneficial.

Comment: what u see in /var/log/cassandra/system.log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I built index on Sid

The key to the lack of performance here is your use of secondary indexes in place of what should be either a clustering key or part of a composite key. Secondary indexes in Cassandra are for assisting in full table scans (an expensive operation) for batch analytics or for early development testing. They are *not* analogous to relational indexes.

So if you want to execute queries like

```
rows = session.execute('SELECT * FROM File WHERE sid = 1 limit 1000')
```

then you need a table whose primary key is sid. If you would like to query based on FID as well then you need two complimentary tables, one keyed on FID and one on SID. At insert time you would place the information in both tables.

Comment: +1 for "They are not analogous to relational indexes."

Comment: On Cassandra version 3 you can use Materialized Views in order to reduce your inserts and have two views; one using FID as key and other for SID. See details https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateMV.html